# Attempting to expose REST Repository info on localhost

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-boot

I've been having a challenging weekend attempting to figure out how to write a simple Rest application. I've posted the stack trace below and it seems all is displaying as find but maybe I'm missing something. My problem I continue to received a 404 error every time I visit http://localhost:8080/

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

BaseEntity class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class BaseEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private final Long id;

        protected BaseEntity() {
            id = null;
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
 @Entity
    public class Course extends BaseEntity{

        private String title;
        private String url;

        protected Course(){
            super();
        }

        public Course(String title, String url) {
            this();
            this.title = title;
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "courses", path = "courses")
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, Long> {
}
```

Database loader:

```
@Component
public abstract class DataBaseLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final CourseRepository courses;

    @Autowired
    public DataBaseLoader(CourseRepository courses){
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public void run (ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception{
        Course course = new Course("Java Basics", "http://www.teamtreehouse.com");
        courses.save(course);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.teamtreehouse</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReviewApi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Print Trace:

```
2017-05-07 16:03:20.138  INFO 533 --- [           main] com.teamtreehouse.App                    : Starting App on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 533 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/ReviewApi/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/ReviewApi)
2017-05-07 16:03:20.142  INFO 533 --- [           main] com.teamtreehouse.App                    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-07 16:03:20.211  INFO 533 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6b0c2d26: startup date [Sun May 07 16:03:20 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-07 16:03:21.725  INFO 533 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e42e6f41] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-07 16:03:22.179  INFO 533 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-07 16:03:22.202  INFO 533 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-07 16:03:22.204  INFO 533 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-05-07 16:03:22.365  INFO 533 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-07 16:03:22.365  INFO 533 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2159 ms
2017-05-07 16:03:22.571  INFO 533 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-07 16:03:22.576  INFO 533 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-07 16:03:22.577  INFO 533 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-07 16:03:22.577  INFO 533 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-07 16:03:22.577  INFO 533 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-07 16:03:23.239  INFO 533 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-07 16:03:23.269  INFO 533 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-07 16:03:23.365  INFO 533 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-05-07 16:03:23.367  INFO 533 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-07 16:03:23.370  INFO 533 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-05-07 16:03:23.417  INFO 533 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-07 16:03:23.667  INFO 533 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-05-07 16:03:24.197  INFO 533 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-05-07 16:03:24.211  INFO 533 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-05-07 16:03:24.263  INFO 533 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-07 16:03:25.044  INFO 533 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6b0c2d26: startup date [Sun May 07 16:03:20 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-07 16:03:25.166  INFO 533 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-05-07 16:03:25.168  INFO 533 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-05-07 16:03:25.219  INFO 533 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-07 16:03:25.219  INFO 533 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-07 16:03:25.294  INFO 533 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-07 16:03:25.680  INFO 533 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-05-07 16:03:25.779  INFO 533 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-07 16:03:25.786  INFO 533 --- [           main] com.teamtreehouse.App                    : Started App in 16.218 seconds (JVM running for 17.23)
2017-05-07 16:03:41.952  INFO 533 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-05-07 16:03:41.952  INFO 533 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-05-07 16:03:41.975  INFO 533 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 23 ms
```

Comment: put your repository class as well

Comment: @pvpkiran added

Comment: is that your complete logs. Because if it is, I don't see the repository endpoints being exposed. maks sure your repository is getting scanned.

Comment: @pvpkiran stupid question, but how does one do that?

Comment: make sure all the classes are one level lower than your main class or use @componentscan to specify the packages to scan